# I have problem when dynamically updating state in useState object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, state

in my useState I have object with bunch of values. I have input and setting it's value to useState[key] dynamically it works. but problem occurs when I want to update values.
when I am calling onChange and {...prev,prev[key]:e.target.value} it's not working.

```js
import { useGlobalContext } from '@/context';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import styles from './Validation.module.css';

function ReusebleForm({fieldType,inputName}) {

  const {generalInfo,setGeneralInfo} = useGlobalContext();

  function displayInfo(e,iName) {
   // this part does not work 
  setGeneralInfo({...generalInfo,...{generalInfo[`${iName}`]:e.target.value}});
  }

  useEffect(()=>{},[generalInfo])

  return (
   
      <input type={`${fieldType}`}  required value={generalInfo[inputName]} name={inputName} onChange={(e) => displayInfo(e,inputName)} />
   
  )
}

export default ReusebleForm
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

this is the state

```js
  const [generalInfo,setGeneralInfo] = useState({
    name: "a",
    surname: "v"
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: solved const value =   generalInfo[iName] = e.target.value;
  setGeneralInfo({...generalInfo,value});

Answer (score 0):

The error says that the useState is not defined.

```
import { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
```

Try importing the useState and check as shown above